# Error when using midasr r package function through rpy2 in python

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I am trying to access functions in 'midasr' r package in python, here's my code:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import pandas as pd

....
base = importr('base')
stats = importr('stats')
midasr = importr('midasr')

x = np.random.rand(11256)
y = np.random.rand(1407)
eq = midasr.midas_r('y ~ mls(x, 0:15, 8, nealmon)', start = 'list(x = c(0, 0))')
```

I get the error:

```
RRuntimeError: Error in new.env(parent = environment(formula)) : 
  use of NULL environment is defunct
```

It works in R as:

```
eq_r <- midas_r(y ~ mls(x, 0:15, 8, nealmon), start = list(x = c(0,0)))
```

So I tried another method:

```
temp = np.empty(len(x))
temp[:] = np.nan
temp[0:1407] = y
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': temp}) 
rdf = pandas2ri.DataFrame(dataframe)
robjects.globalenv['dataframe'] = dataframe
eq = midasr.midas_r('y[1:1407] ~ mls(x, 0:15, 8, nealmon)', data=rdf, start = 'list(x = c(0, 0))')
```

Still the same error.

After I get the response from @Parfeit, I tried:

```
formula = robjects.Formula('y_ro ~ mls(x_ro, 0:15, 8, nealmon)')
env = formula.environment
env["y_ro"] = y_ro
env["x_ro"] = x_ro
slist = robjects.ListVector({'x_ro': robjects.IntVector((0, 0))})
eq = midasr.midas_r(formula, start = slist)
```

But now I get:

```
RRuntimeError: Error in midas_r.fit(prepmd) : 
  The optimisation algorithm of MIDAS regression failed with the following message:
Error in y - mdsrhs(p) : non-conformable arrays

Please try other starting values or a different optimisation function
```

However I can successfully run the same datasets in r.

Anyone know how to fix this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider building your formula, passing in current values and `start` argument with a passed in Python object:

```
x = np.random.rand(11256)
y = np.random.rand(1407)

formula = robjects.Formula('y ~ x')
env = formula.environment
env["y"] = y
env["x"] = midasr.mls(x, robjects.IntVector(range(15)), 8, midasr.nealmon)    # MLS() FCT

slist = robjects.ListVector({'x': robjects.IntVector((0, 0))})                # R LIST: $x [1] 0 0

eq = midasr.midas_r(formula, start = slist)
```

Comment: Thanks for response! `env["x"] = midasr.mls(x, range(15), 8, nealmon) ` should be  `env["x"] = midasr.mls(x, np.array(range(16)), 8, 'nealmon')`. But after I run this, I got `Error in as.vector(x$model[, -1] %*% x$midas_coefficients) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.vector': Error in x$model[, -1] %*% x$midas_coefficients : 
  non-conformable arguments`

Comment: Where does `nealmon` derive? If it is a named object, it needs to be defined in Python. And R's `0:15` translates as Python's `range(15)`, not `np.array()`. And actually, it  should be `robjects.IntVector(range(15))` per the [docs](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/vector.html).

Comment: `nealmon` is a weight function in midasr package. `np.array()` and `robjects.IntVector(range(15))` work the same way, both generate corrctly.

Comment: @Parfeit But it generates `Error in as.vector(x$model[, -1] %*% x$midas_coefficients) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.vector': Error in x$model[, -1] %*% x$midas_coefficients : 
  non-conformable arguments`

Comment: Then you need to qualify the function as Python requires it of every object: `midasr.nealmon`. I wished I had that R package to fully test.

Comment: @Parfeit, thanks! Does `'nealmon'` mean passing that into r environment?  which I think is the same with midasr.nealmon. However, even passing midasr.nealmon as you wrote above, it shows the same error saying: `Error in as.vector(x$model[, -1] %*% x$midas_coefficients) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.vector': Error in x$model[, -1] %*% x$midas_coefficients : 
  non-conformable arguments`

Comment: This package is not heavily used, that's why I am struggling a lot with it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using the same code as Parfait and adding the start argument with the right number of elements which is equal to the number of variables

```
 x = np.random.rand(11256)
 y = np.random.rand(1407)

 formula = robjects.Formula('y ~ x')
 env = formula.environment
 env["y"] = y
 env["x"] = midasr.mls(x, robjects.IntVector(range(16)), 8, midasr.nealmon)# MLS() FCT

 slist = robjects.ListVector({'x': robjects.IntVector(base.rep(0,16))})# R LIST: $x [1] 0 0

 eq = midasr.midas_r(formula, start = slist)
```